# Making an application to upload zip files in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails. 
**I need to create a rails application that helps me to upload zip or tar files to it.** 
I am using rails 2.3
is there any gem that can help me to do this swiftly or some tutorial.
**I am new so step by step instructions will be much much appreciated.** 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) code you've applied to the problem. In addition, please post **relevant** error messages *verbatim*, and take the time to share the steps you've taken so far to research or resolve things on your own.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for either the paperclip or carrierwave gems and followed them? Once you get stuck with either of those, please post a new question and follow CodeGnome's advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you use rails 2 you can use [Paperclip](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)

If you use rails 3 you can use [Carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave)

Answer (score 0):

Gemfile

```
gem "paperclip", "~> 5.0.0"
```

Create a file inside initializers:
app/config/initializers/paperclip.rb

```
module Paperclip
  class MediaTypeSpoofDetector
    def spoofed?
      false
    end
  end
end
```

Then upload zip or any Image file using papeclip.